# JavaScript variable changes to outcome the line after it is defined

Tags: javascript

I am working on creating a computer bot that plays itself at chopsticks. I have invented a `while` loop to run until one of the computers wins. I store the computer's `gameState` in a variable that looks like `[[1,1],[1,1]]`. The first item in the list is player one, and his left hand and right hand values are at 1. The second player is the same way. However, the line after I define `gameState`, I `console.log()` the `gameState` variable and get the end result of the game, *the line after I define it as* `[[1,1],[1,1]]`. The problem with this is that during the while loop, I'm not able to get information about the moves that the computer is making. Help!

Here is my code:

```
function makeMove(s, player, m) { //source, player, move
  //if it is player 2, flip it around
  if (player == 2) {
    var s = [s[1], s[0]];
  }
  var target;
  var source;

  //move 0 is when the left hand targets the opponent's right hand
  //move 1 is when the right hand targets the opponent's left hand
  //move 2 is when the left hand targets the opponent's left hand
  //move 3 is when the right hand targets the opponent's right hand

  //the state [[1,1],[1,1]] stores the values of each hand and each opponent

  if (m == 0 || m == 3) {
    target = [1, 0];
  } else {
    target = [1, 1];
  }
  if (m == 0 || m == 2) {
    source = [0, 0];
  } else {
    source = [0, 1];
  }
    s[target[0]][target[1]] += s[source[0]][source[1]];
    s[target[0]][target[1]] %= 5;

  if (player == 2) {
    s = [s[1], s[0]];
  }
  return s;
}

function playmatch() {
  //the original state, 
  var gameState = [[1, 1], [1, 1]];
  //right after I create the value, for some reason it changes to the end result when I log it the next line.
  console.log(gameState);
    var winner = -1;
   while (winner == -1) {
     var choice = [0,1,2,3];
      var move = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
      gameState = makeMove(gameState, 1, move);
     var move = choice[Math.floor(Math.random() * choice.length)];
      gameState = makeMove(gameState, 2, move);
      if (gameState[0][0] == 0 && gameState[0][1] == 0) {
      winner = 2;
    }
    if (gameState[1][0] == 0 && gameState[1][1] == 0) {
      winner = 1;
    }
     console.log(gameState);
    }
return winner;
  }
playmatch();
```

And a link to the codepen pen: https://codepen.io/gmoyer/pen/EeepbE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of [`console.log`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#log) is not standardized. As suggested by MDN, you should [serialize your object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects).

Do this

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

instead of

```
console.log(obj);
```

to ensure that what is passed to `console.log` is a snapshot of the object at that moment in time rather than a reference to the object. I assume that `console.log` is not executing right when you call it and is given a reference to your array. Thus, your array changes, and later when `console.log` executes, it logs the changed array.